# How to convert Varbinary Column to Base64 String to be saved as Json?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, asp.net-core

On a SQL database I have a Varbinary column (Content) and I ran the query in Azure Data Studio:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Content
FROM Files
```

And the result is:

```
Id   Name   Content
1    File1  0xFFD8FFE000104A464946000102 ... 
2    File2  0xFFD8FFE000104A464946000102 ...
```

I exported the result o JSON and tried to deserialise it using Asp.NET Core Json Deserialiser:

```
  Byte[] json = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path);

  List<File> files = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<File>>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(json));
```

Where File is the following class:

```
public class File {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Byte[] Content { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

But during deserialisation I got the error:

```
Cannot decode JSON text that is not encoded as valid Base64 to bytes.
```

I tried to change my SQL query to:

```
SELECT Id, Name, CAST(CAST('' as XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("Content"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) as [Content]
FROM Files
```

But I got the same error during deserialisation.

How to convert the varbinary column to Base64 string to be saved as JSON?

**Update**

I tried to check if it is a Base64 string (to not rely only on the deserialiser) using:

```
Span<byte> buffer = new Span<byte>(new byte[content.Length]);
var isBase64 = Convert.TryFromBase64String(content, buffer , out int parsed);
```

But I always get false ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Id, Name, CAST('' as XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("Content"))', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') as [Content]
FROM Files



declare @binary varbinary(max) = cast(N'{"message":"OK"}' as varbinary(max))
select CAST('' as XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@binary"))', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') -- ewAiAG0AZQBzAHMAYQBnAGUAIgA6ACIATwBLACIAfQA=

Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("ewAiAG0AZQBzAHMAYQBnAGUAIgA6ACIATwBLACIAfQA="))); --{"message":"OK"}
```

Comment: I tried your code and I got the same error ... I added to my question some extra C# code I used to validate if it is a Base64 string to not rely only on the Json deserialiser exception. And I get false.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known github issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30793#issuecomment-424435891).

A valid base64-encoded string length is always a multiple of 4 (If there is not enough input-data, padding `=` will therefore get added).

Only one padding `=` character is accepted by the decoder in 2.1.(Asp.net core 3.0 is also accepted only one padding `=` after my testing).

To fix such case, be sure that `Content` in your json string should be a multiple of 4.